# Encrypt/De-crypt using EnvelopedCms throws BadData exception

Tags: c#, encryption

I have this:

```
static string Encrypt(string message)
{
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, c_thumbPrint, false);

    if (cert.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] messageAsByteArray = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(message);
    var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(messageAsByteArray);
    var envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms(contentInfo);
    envelopedCms.Encrypt(new CmsRecipient(cert[0]));

    return new UnicodeEncoding().GetString(envelopedCms.Encode());
}


static string Decrypt(string message)
{
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, c_thumbPrint, false);

    if (cert.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms();
    var messageAsBytes = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(message);
    envelopedCms.Decode(messageAsBytes);
    envelopedCms.Decrypt(cert); //Throws BadData exception
    var decryptedBytes = envelopedCms.ContentInfo.Content;
    return new UnicodeEncoding().GetString(decryptedBytes);
}
```

And I'm running:

```
Console.WriteLine(Decrypt(Encrypt("Pikachu"));
```

Unfortunately, the commented line above (`envelopedCms.Decrypt(cert)`) throws

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException ("Bad Data")
```

My best guess is that I'm not converting the encrypted string to a byte array correctly. Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(envelopedCms.Encode());
```

for your encryption routine as the encoding result not necessarily returns data that can be represented as string (0 char)

Try

```
envelopedCms.Decrypt();
```

for your decryption routine. This searches only in StoreName.My (and any StoreLocation). If you supply a certificate collection for the Decrypt() function these certificates must contain a private key. The X509Store only grants access to the public key.

Furthermore not all certificates are suitable for encoding/decoding. They must contain at least a private key. You might get an exception complaining about an invalid key. Don't yet know where that comes from.